# Login redirect Issue in post comment area in PHP

Tags: php, authentication, redirect

If someone wishes to comment on any item e.g. and article or forum item, etc. on my site. It prompts them to login/create account. Is it possible to make sure that when the client logs in it takes them back to the comment they wanted to make?

But now it's going not like this flow. The user not logging in redirects to the login page, but I want, after logging in to this section, the user is automatically redirected to the current post comment area. Is there a way?

```
<?php if ($sessionUser == 1 || $sessionSeller == 1 || $sessionadmin == 1) { ?>

    <form class="cp_form"
          action="article_comments_db.php"
          method="post"
          name="frm_comment"
          id="frm_comment">

        <div id="div_req_comment" class="cp_infopanel_off">
            <span><?= $_Reviews ?></span>:<span class="red">*</span>

            <textarea class="cp_textarea"
                      id="req_comment"
                      name="req_comment"
                      onBlur="do_blur(this.id)"
                      onFocus="do_focus(this.id)"></textarea>

            <div id="infobox_req_comment" class="cp_infobox"></div>
        </div>

        <input type="button"
               id="btn_submit"
               class="rp_button"
               value="<?= $_Submit ?>"
               onClick="validate_form('frm_comment')" />

        <input type="hidden"
               name="id" value="<?php echo $id ?>" />
    </form>

<?php } else {
?>

    <br/><br/>
    <div align="right">

        <input type="button"
               id="btn_submit"
               class="rp_button"
               value=" <?= $_Post_comment ?> "
               onClick="window.location.href='login.php?event=Account'" />
    </div>

<?php
}
```

Comment: Your code doesn't seem to show correctly.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You could call your login.php?event=Account with an ID or the URL ([urlencode](http://php.net/manual/en/function.urlencode.php)) of the current page visited by the user.

```
login.php?event=Account&visitedpageid=1
```

In the loginform you could fetch the ID/URL with $_GET and put it in a hidden input.

```
<input type="hidden" name="visitedpage" value="<?php echo $_GET['visitedpageid']; ?>">
```

If login was correct, you then redirect by using the POST-value of that hidden input.

```
$_POST['visitedpage']
```

Please make sure you check if the get-parameter is set ([isset](http://www.php.net/manual/en/function.isset.php)) and matches to an existing page.

Comment: Last step once more explain please "$_POST['visitedpage']
". where  i will use this post method ?

Comment: When you check the username and password you'll need to check the $_POST-array from your loginform. At the point where you identified the user as logged in, you can redirect by using the $_POST-value of your hidden input (e.g. with header-function).

Answer (score 0):

I can give you the idea of *how* it can be achieved.

1. While redirecting to your login page, check if `$_SERVER['HTTP_REFERER']` is empty or not. If not empty, then save it in to a session.
2. After a successful login, check whether the user came from the another page or not using the value you saved into your session.

If not empty, then redirect the user to the same page as defined into your session variable. And before redirecting, hold the session value in a variable and destroy this session variable.

Comment: how to use $_SERVER['HTTP_REFERER'] for this issue ?

Comment: Try to print this variable at the top of your login page and come from the products page. you will get the url of the products page that you can store into session.